# .NET Core: Read /dev/ file

Tags: c#, .net-core

Connecting my RFID reader to my Linux machine it get installed automatically. I can see its output using `hexdump /dev/hidraw0`.

I want to read that input using C# .NET Core. I works fine using Pinvoke. Here the opening part (details [over here](https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2017/08/07/using-net-core-2-on-raspbian-jessie-to-read-serial-data-from-an-arduino/)):

```
[DllImport("libc")]
public static extern int open(string pathname, OpenFlags flags);

int fd = open("/dev/hidraw0", OpenFlags.O_RDONLY);
```

Is it possible to do the opening and reading using .NET Core methods? `/dev/hidraw0` is just a (device) file, right? Wouldn't it be possible to use `FileStream` or `BinaryReader`? The problem I am facing: I only find methods which read available data, but I need a blocking read method which wait until data is available and then return it. Or maybe there is a `DataAvailable` event or alike?

Basically my question boils down to: Am a stuck with libc's `read()` and `open()`  methods or is there a .NET Core way for reading `/dev/` files?

Comment: You could ask this on the dotnet/corefx or dotnet/iot GitHub repos which deal with hardware abstractions. Note that dotnet/iot also does libc interop for things like communicating with I2C devices.

Comment: I just found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readblock?view=netframework-4.7.2 -- Sounds promising but I did not investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you: [Linux & Dotnet – Read from a device file](https://blog.honosoft.com/2019/03/12/linux-dotnet-read-from-a-device-file/)

```
public void ReadDeviceStream(CancellationToken stoppingToken) 
{
  // Use the device file
  var targetFile = new FileInfo("/dev/inputs/event1");
  // Open a stream
  using (FileStream fs = targetFile.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
  {
    stoppingToken.Register(() => fs?.Close());
    int blockId = 1;
    // A big buffer, for simplicity purpose and to receive the entire touch report. We should use
    // the proper buffer size based on the event size. Note that we could also
    // use the binary reader
    var buffer = new byte[1024];
    // Read until the token gets cancelled
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested && fs.Read(buffer) > 0)
    {
      ShowBinaryContent(blockId, buffer);
      blockId++;
    }
  }
}
public void ShowBinaryContent(int blockId, byte[] buffer)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"Block #{blockId}");
  Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(bytes)); // Hex format: AB-1D...
  Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
}
```